# Detect if variable provides a function in template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function template which is called with different values, i.e.

```
template <typename T>
T do_calculations(const T &var)
{
     T return_variable;
     //Do calculations
     return return_variable;
}
```

Now the calculations depend on the type of the variable `var`. `T` can either be a scalar (such as `double` or `int`), a vector (such as `std::vector<>` or other types) or a matrix. I know that I can differentiate between for example a `std::vector` and a `double` by knowing that `double` does not have a member function called `size()`. How can I implement that in my code above? My aim is to have similar code to this:

```
template <typename T>
T do_calculations(const T &var)
{
     T return_variable;
     if(T.has_function_size())
         //Do calculations on vector
     else
         //Do calculations on scalar
     return return_variable;
}
```

I can not do a simple check if `T` is a known type due to having a lot of different input types, but I know that all possible types having a function `size()` behave similar enough for me.

Now my problem is:
My code for the vector calculation loops over all elements, but the code for scalar calculation only over the single element:

```
template <typename T>
T do_calculations(const T &var)
{
     T return_variable;
     if(T.has_function_size())
         for(size_t i = 0; i < T.size(); ++i)
             return_variable[i] = func(var[i]);
     else
         return_variable = func(var);
     return return_variable;
}
```

with `func()` a function taking a scalar.
Compilation fails with the error that I can not apply `func()` to a vector (or my own type). Do I have to create separate functions for that, or can I tell the compiler that I know what I do?

Comment: This could answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence

Comment: @JomsDev: Unfortunately not fully, I expanded the question.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!